# Undefined reference to function using a Makefile and GTest

Tags: c++, makefile, googletest

I am new to Makefiles and I have trouble with an undefined reference to a function. The directory structure is the following:

```
├── linkedlist.cc
├── linkedlist.h
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main.cc
│   │   ├── removeduplicates.cc
│   │   ├── removeduplicates_unittest.cc
│   └── test
│       ├── Makefile
```

removeduplicates.cc and removeduplicates_unittest.cc import the declarations from linkedlist.h and the definitions from linkedlist.cc. Also removeduplicates.cc defines new functions that are declared in linkedlist.h but not defined in linkedlist.cc.

The sample Makefile file that uses GTest is taken from the GTest example in the repo and looks like the following. It is only modified to include the files above.

```
# A sample Makefile for building Google Test and using it in user
# tests.  Please tweak it to suit your environment and project.  You
# may want to move it to your project's root directory.
#
# SYNOPSIS:
#
#   make [all]  - makes everything.
#   make TARGET - makes the given target.
#   make clean  - removes all files generated by make.

# Please tweak the following variable definitions as needed by your
# project, except GTEST_HEADERS, which you can use in your own targets
# but shouldn't modify.

# Points to the root of Google Test, relative to where this file is.
# Remember to tweak this if you move this file.
GTEST_DIR = ../../../GMOCK_ROOT/GTEST_DIR/googletest/

# Where to find user code.
USER_DIR = ../src
BASE_DIR = ../..

# Flags passed to the preprocessor.
# Set Google Test's header directory as a system directory, such that
# the compiler doesn't generate warnings in Google Test headers.
CPPFLAGS += -isystem $(GTEST_DIR)/include

# Flags passed to the C++ compiler.
CXXFLAGS += -I.. -std=c++17 -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread

# All tests produced by this Makefile.  Remember to add new tests you
# created to the list.
TESTS = removeduplicates_unittest

# All Google Test headers.  Usually you shouldn't change this
# definition.
GTEST_HEADERS = $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/*.h \
                $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/internal/*.h

# House-keeping build targets.

all : $(TESTS)

clean :
    rm -f $(TESTS) gtest.a gtest_main.a *.o

# Builds gtest.a and gtest_main.a.

# Usually you shouldn't tweak such internal variables, indicated by a
# trailing _.
GTEST_SRCS_ = $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.cc $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)

# For simplicity and to avoid depending on Google Test's
# implementation details, the dependencies specified below are
# conservative and not optimized.  This is fine as Google Test
# compiles fast and for ordinary users its source rarely changes.
gtest-all.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
            $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc

gtest_main.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
            $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc

gtest.a : gtest-all.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

gtest_main.a : gtest-all.o gtest_main.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

# Builds a sample test.  A test should link with either gtest.a or
# gtest_main.a, depending on whether it defines its own main()
# function.

removeduplicates.o : $(USER_DIR)/removeduplicates.cc $(BASE_DIR)/linkedlist.h $(BASE_DIR)/linkedlist.cc $(GTEST_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(BASE_DIR)/linkedlist.cc $(USER_DIR)/removeduplicates.cc 

removeduplicates_unittest.o : $(USER_DIR)/removeduplicates_unittest.cc $(BASE_DIR)/linkedlist.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/removeduplicates_unittest.cc

removeduplicates_unittest : removeduplicates.o removeduplicates_unittest.o gtest_main.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@
```

I think the error comes from this line but I'm not sure how to modify it:

```
CXXFLAGS += -I.. -std=c++17 -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread
```

The error I get (among others similar) is:

```
/RemoveDuplicates/test/../src/removeduplicates_unittest.cc:10: undefined reference to `LinkedList::LinkedList(std::initializer_list<int>)'
```

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

EDIT1: I followed the suggestion given by @Some programmer dude but now I have functions that are defined multiple times:

```
g++ -isystem ../../../GMOCK_ROOT/GTEST_DIR/googletest//include -I.. -std=c++17 -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread -lpthread removeduplicates.o removeduplicates_unittest.o ../../linkedlist.o gtest_main.a -o removeduplicates_unittest
../../linkedlist.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
../../linkedlist.o: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
../../linkedlist.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
../../linkedlist.o: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
../../linkedlist.o: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
../../linkedlist.o: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
../../linkedlist.o:(.data+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in ../../linkedlist.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'removeduplicates_unittest' failed
make: *** [removeduplicates_unittest] Error 1
```

Comment: You don't seem to be building with the source (or object) file that you want to test, then one containing the implementation of `LinkedList`.

Comment: Also, the file you show is a plain `Makefile`, not a CMake `CmakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Can you please tell me where the problem lies? Which line would need to be modified? My mistake for calling it a CMake file, I'll edit the post to show only a Makefile instead of cmake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your `Makefile` you have the dependencies for the test you're building. The last of those, where you list the test executable `removeduplicates_unittest` you need to list the object file `$(BASE_DIR)/linkedlist.o` as well:

```
#                                                                          Added this dependency
#                                                                          vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
removeduplicates_unittest : removeduplicates.o removeduplicates_unittest.o $(BASE_DIR)/linkedlist.o gtest_main.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@
```

That will lead to the `linkedlist.o` file being linked into the executable.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried making this modification but now I get an error regarding multiple definitions of some files. Do you know what could be wrong with this now?

Comment: @Razvan It seems that `linkedlist.o` is not built as a proper object file, but rather an executable file. You may want to add a specific target to build it properly. I recommend you read some tutorials on `make` and makefiles.

Comment: Yes that's a good idea. I will mark your answer as the solution as it solved the initial problem.